# Dodecahedron texture does not appear

Tags: html, three.js

I'm trying to create a dodecahedron using ThreeJS and add a texture on each face. I'm also trying using Raycaster to detect which face i'm clicking on.

Although the code works for a cube, when I try the dodecahedron, the texture does not appear and the interesects from raycaster are empty.

You can see a complete example in [jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/91g79g6t/3/).

```
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh, geometry, controls;
        var raycaster, mouse, clock; 

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            clock = new THREE.Clock();
            raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1200 );      
            camera.position.set(60, 40, 100);


            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            var lights = [];
            lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
            lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
            lights[2] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );

            lights[0].position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
            lights[1].position.set( 100, 200, 100 );
            lights[2].position.set( -100, -200, -100 );

            scene.add( lights[0] );
            scene.add( lights[1] );
            scene.add( lights[2] );



            //
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


            var imgUrl = 'http://n1.xtek.gr/ascsa/applications/maps-3d/textures/brick.jpg';
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( imgUrl );


            geometry = createGeometry();


            var shapeMaterials = [ 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }),

                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false }), 
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, map: texture, transparent: false })
            ]; 

            var shapeMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(shapeMaterials); 

            mesh = new THREE.Object3D()         
            mesh.add( new THREE.LineSegments(

                geometry,

                new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                    //color: 0xffffff,
                    transparent: true,
                    opacity: 0.5
                })

            ));


            mesh.add( new THREE.Mesh(
                geometry,
                shapeMaterial
            ));

            scene.add( mesh );


            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

        }


        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }


        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;


            var render = function(){    

                geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
                geometry.morphTargetsNeedUpdate = true;
                geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

                for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
                    //console.log("FACE: "+i);
                    var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
                    face.materials = [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) ];
                }

                mesh.updateMatrix();
                controls.update();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);  
            }
            render();

        }


        function createGeometry () {

            // geometry
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            // vertices
            geometry.vertices = [
                new THREE.Vector3( 2.04772293123743050, -4.09327412386437040, -5.74908146957292670),
                new THREE.Vector3(  7.02732984841516030, 1.40331541320251810, -1.62706516545639390),
                new THREE.Vector3( 4.22549114271519950, -1.62031854283173550,  5.78962800381778210),
                new THREE.Vector3( 0.75411577446253997,  7.11690807989861880, -1.66761169970125600),
                new THREE.Vector3(-0.75411577446252998, -7.11690807989862510,  1.66761169970125020),
                new THREE.Vector3(-4.22549114271518980,  1.62031854283173260, -5.78962800381778920),
                new THREE.Vector3( -2.0477229312374288,  4.09327412386436950,  5.74908146957292670),
                new THREE.Vector3(-7.02732984841515230, -1.40331541320252740,  1.62706516545639970),
                new THREE.Vector3( 6.27321407395262300, -5.71359266669610030,  0.04054653424485652),
                new THREE.Vector3( 2.80183870569996340,  3.02363395603425690, -7.41669316927418000),
                new THREE.Vector3( 4.97960691717773150,  5.49658953706689160,  4.12201630411653590),
                new THREE.Vector3(-2.80183870569996340, -3.02363395603425690,  7.41669316927418000),
                new THREE.Vector3(-4.97960691717773150, -5.49658953706689160, -4.12201630411653590),
                new THREE.Vector3(-6.27321407395262480,  5.71359266669610210, -0.04054653424485653)
            ];

            // faces - in counterclockwise winding order - important!
            geometry.faces.push(
                new THREE.Face3( 8, 0, 9 ),  new THREE.Face3( 9, 1, 8 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 8, 1, 10 ), new THREE.Face3( 10, 2, 8 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 8, 2, 11 ), new THREE.Face3( 11, 4, 8 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 8, 4, 12 ), new THREE.Face3( 12, 0, 8 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 12, 5, 9 ), new THREE.Face3( 9, 0, 12 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 13, 3, 9 ), new THREE.Face3( 9, 5, 13 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 10, 1, 9 ), new THREE.Face3( 9, 3, 10 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 10, 3, 13 ), new THREE.Face3( 13, 6, 10 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 11, 2, 10 ), new THREE.Face3( 10, 6, 11 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 11, 7, 12 ), new THREE.Face3( 12, 4, 11 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 12, 7, 13 ), new THREE.Face3( 13, 5, 12 ),
                new THREE.Face3( 13, 7, 11 ), new THREE.Face3( 11, 6, 13 )
            );

            // normals ( since they are not specified directly )
            geometry.computeFaceNormals();
            geometry.computeVertexNormals();

            return geometry;
        }




        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
            console.log( intersects );
            for(i=0; i<intersects.length; i++) {
                var dist = intersects[i].distance;
                var faceIndex = intersects[i].faceIndex;
                if(faceIndex != null) {
                    console.log("Target : "+faceIndex+" [dist="+dist+"]");
                    intersects[i].object.material.materials[faceIndex].color.setHex( 0xff4d4d );

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt load for me, but why not use ```THREE.DodecahedronGeometry```? http://jsfiddle.net/5dk9980o/1/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work great!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official `THREE.DodecahedronGeometry` for this:

```
var shapeMaterial = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
var geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry( 10, 0 );
var dodecahedron = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shapeMaterial );
scene.add( dodecahedron );
```

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/DodecahedronGeometry